# Easiest way to get both expression and result in latex in Mathematica on command line

Tags: latex

I'm trying to build a function that takes in an expression in unevaluated form, and then returns the full equation in LaTeX, e.g. I would like to feed in the below  and receive the LaTeX output `\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x}=0`.

```
Limit[1/x, x->Infinity]
```

I'm working from the command line so I would prefer not to use the Notebook features if possible.

I've tried working with a bunch of variants of `Hold, HoldForm, Release` etc to little avail. Many thanks!

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{x}=0$$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Clear[evalTeX, evalLastTeX];

SetAttributes[evalTeX, HoldFirst];
evalTeX[expr_] := ToString@TeXForm@HoldForm@expr <> " = " <>
   ToString@TeXForm@ReleaseHold@expr

evalTeX[Limit[1/x, x -> Infinity]]
(* \underset{x\to \infty }{\text{lim}}\frac{1}{x} = 0 *)

evalTeX[Integrate[x^(5/2), {x, 0, 2}]]
(* \int_0^2 x^{5/2} \, dx = \frac{16 \sqrt{2}}{7} *)
```

For the last input, we can use `In[-1]` and trace its evaluation:

```
evalLastTeX[] := evalTeX@Evaluate@Trace[In[-1]][[5]];

Sqrt[81]
(* 9 *)

evalLastTeX[]
(* \sqrt{81} = 9 *)
```

Comment: This is fantastic, thank you. Exactly what I wanted.

Is there a way to extend it so it could work on the previous result?

`evalTeX[Limit[1/x, x -> Infinity]]` and `Limit[1/x, x -> Infinity] // evalTeX` work but running `Limit[1/x, x -> Infinity]` and then `evalTeX[%]` does not.

Comment: @toomey8, please see my edit. Note that I've also changed a bit ``evalTeX`` so you should re-evaluate it.

Comment: Thanks, this is perfect!